# "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app" - but we are under the cap

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

An internal script I use together with my research team uses the Drive API to automate file download from Drive. Some accounts, arbitrarily as far as I could tell, get the "temporarily disabled" message instead of the regular authorization screen.

The behavior is per account - some accounts always get the "temporarily disabled" screen, while the rest always get the desired auth screen. Switching accounts sometimes helps in case one's second account is in the "good group" that gets the auth screen.

We use @gmail accounts (not gsuite). The app uses the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` scope. The app has not been verified and I am aware of the cap when using sensitive scopes. It seems from the dashboard that we are below the user cap. Looking at **OAuth consent screen > OAuth rate limits > Your user cap** I see "5 users / 100 user cap".

Can someone explain this behavior?
Am I looking at the right thing on the dashboard?
Can I use a less sensitive scope that will not require verification? We only need to download specific files/folders.

Answer (score 1):

If an app or service shows the `Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app` message it means that Google paralyzed the app/service for security reasons. The only thing that you can do is go through the [verification](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865#verification) process.

Comment: The app doesn't seem completely paralyzed because some accounts do manage to activate it. Unless this is a part of how paralysis works?

Comment: Hi @AmitLavon! Yes, you are correct, the disabling may not affect every user. Google does it based on the activity and scopes used in the app, so some users can be considered in a higher risk than others. Whatever are the reasons, the only step forward is to complete the verification process.